# How do I use filter to show input values?

Tags: jquery, filter, contains

I am trying to hide all `<li>` elements, and then only show those `<li>`s containing a child `<p>` with text matching the value of the input/search field.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<ul class="items">

    <li class="item">
        <p class="keywords" style="display: none;">skins, hair</p>//keywords
        <a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="koalahat.jpg"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
        <p class="keywords" style="display: none;">hair</p>
        <a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="goosehat.jpg"></a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var typed = $(this).val(); //get the input field value
    $('.items li').hide() //hide all LIs...
    $('.items li').filter(function(){ //filter all LIs that...
        $('.items li p.keywords:contains(typed)').parent().show(); //... that contain the typed keywords, and show them.
    });
    console.log(typed);
})
```

I can't figure out why changing `$('.items li p.keywords:contains(typed)')` to `$('.items li p.keywords:contains("skins")')` returns the desired output, the former does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation issue. Try this:

```
$('p.keywords:contains("' + typed + '")', this).parent().show();
```

i think all you would need is:

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var typed = this.value; //get the input field value
    $('.items li').hide() //hide all LIs...
    $('.items li').find('p.keywords:contains("' + typed + '")', this).parent().show();
    console.log(typed);
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3xcH/)**

While issue is that in the selector `$('.items li p.keywords:contains(typed)')` typed is considered as a string and not a variable so its value is not evaluated. Instead you should concatenate the variable with the string. And also you can do away with the filter, just the selector is enough.